# How do I resolve the error "code": "22001" in postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

Hello  I want to implement database to the node project I'm working on. On testing the authentication endpoint I getting the error `"message": { "length": 164, "name": "error", "severity": "ERROR", "code": "22001", "file": "d:\\pginstaller_13.auto\\postgres.windows-x64\\src\\backend\\utils\\adt\\varchar.c", "line": "635", "routine": "varchar" }` via postman
I am not certain I did my database set up correctly, any advice on how to set up postgresql environment properly such that I can deploy to Heroku and  please how can I resolve the error ?

Auth.js

```
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const pool = require('../configuration/config');
const validate = require('../middleware/auth.validation')



const signup = async  (request, response)=>{
    try {
        //1. destructure req.body
    const {firstname, lastname, username, email, password} = request.body;
    //2. validate user input
    const validationError = validate.signup(firstname,lastname,username, email, password)
if(validationError.message){
    return response.status(400).json({status:'Validation Error', message: validationError.message})
}
//3. check if user exist (if user exist , throw err)
const userExist = await pool.query(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = $1`, [username]);
if(userExist.rows.length !== 0){
    return response.status(401).json({message: "User Already Exist"})
}
// 4. hash user password
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt)
//5. Insert user into db
const newUser = await pool.query('INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, username, email, password) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING *', [firstname, lastname, username,email, hashPassword]);
response.json(newUser)

// 6. generate jwt token
} catch (error) {
    response.status(500).send({message:error})
}

}

module.exports = {signup}
```

config.js

```
require('dotenv').config()

const { Pool } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool({
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
})
pool.on('connect', ()=>{
  console.log('connected to database')
})


module.exports = pool
```

pool.js `database Schema`

```
require('dotenv').config()

const { Pool } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool({
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
  password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
})
pool.on('connect', ()=>{
  console.log('connected to database')
})


module.exports = pool
```

queries.js

```
const pool = require('./pool')

module.exports = {
  /**
   * DB Query
   * @param {object} req
   * @param {object} res
   * @returns {object} object
   */
  query(quertText, params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.query(quertText, params)
        .then((res) => {
          resolve(res);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that it gives you the exact source code line in the [postgres source code](https://doxygen.postgresql.org/varchar_8c_source.html) but not the actual error message... Looking at line 635 of src/backend/utils/adt/varchar.c gives:

```
            ereport(ERROR,
                     (errcode(ERRCODE_STRING_DATA_RIGHT_TRUNCATION),
                      errmsg("value too long for type character varying(%d)",
                             maxlen)));
```

So, yeah, the column was probably declared as VARCHAR(N) and the string you're trying to put in the column has more than N characters, so it throws an error.

Comment: but I added the schema in `pool.js` could it be that I didn't specify the schema properly or its not connected ?

Comment: check the CREATE TABLE

Comment: PostgreSQL certainly sends the error message to the client. You just failed to read it.

Comment: Yeah I hope it would show the message, but it isn't in the question!